# Node Red UI Layout

Tags: node-red

I am new to using Node Red on my Raspberry Pi.  Yes, I spent a few hours searching online for my issue.

I do a google search of Node Red dashboard images for ideas, and I see a lot of really well laid-out screen shots.  But my question is pretty basic.  How do I control where on the web page do my input and output nodes appear?  Is there a tutorial somewhere about creating a custom UI page?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you looked at the README? Asking for tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: What's wrong with asking if a tutorial exists?  Yes, I looked at README.md, but I think you didn't understand my question.  I can't find anyplace where I can control the placement of nodes on the /ui webpage.  On the webpage the inputs are all grouped together, the outputs are all grouped together.  My question is how do I ungroup them and put an input and corresponding outputs together?

Comment: Requests for tutorials end up being link only answers which are rapidly become useless when the link breaks. A request for a Tutorial/book or software library is one of the valid reasons to close a question. See point 4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

When you install the *node-red-nodes-dashboard* nodes you get a new sidebar added next to the **info** and **debug** tabs. This is sub-divided into 3 sections:

1. Layout
2. Theme
3. Site

[image]

As expected the Layout section lets you manipulate the layout of the various widgets, from here you can drag and drop widgets between tabs and groups as well as change the order that widgets appear in a group.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I couldn't find in the Node Red docs.